# How to combile multiple request in RxJava2?

Tags: android, rx-java2

I want to use Rxjava 2 to get my ip address, I request 2 api (because sometimes the api is faulty)

I want:

- Get the result of the first successful request returned
- Do not jump to error when the request fails
- If both requests fail, it will get the default value

How do I do. Please just help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`onError()` / `onErrorResumeNext()` are your firends](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators).

There are multiple ways to achieve what you describe, one wouldbe to do something like:

```
getIpV1()
  .onErrorResumeNext(
    getIpV2().onErrorReturn(defaulValue)
  )
```

Here the requests would run one aftern another.

To have them run in parallel, see `combineLatest()` or `zip()`

```
s1 = getIpV1().onErrorReturn(defaulValue)
s2 = getIpV2().onErrorReturn(defaulValue)
Observable.zip(s1, s2, {s1, s2 -> TODO("merge")})
```

Comment: Thank @LordFlash, I will check your answer and feedback to you :)

Comment: Thank you so much @Lord Flash